# how to get multiple records from one table using group by query in mysql

Tags: mysql

ContentDetails Table has below contentTypes.
contentType -- live , vod , movie.

Each contentType has 100 reocrds (live -100,vod-100,movie - 100) .

I want multiple records from each contentType.

Query :

```
 SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM  `ContentDetails ` ORDER BY `contentid   ` ASC ) AS a GROUP BY `contentType` limit 0,100;
```

After exceuting aove query getting below results .

only one live , one vod and one movie comes.

But my requirement is:

10 live contents , 10 vod contents and 10 movie contens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be you want 10 items from each content type, if yes then you may use below query-

```
SELECT x.*
FROM (SELECT t.*,
               CASE 
                 WHEN @category != t.contentType THEN @rownum := 1 
                 ELSE @rownum := @rownum + 1 
               END AS rank,
               @category := t.contentType AS var_category
          FROM contentDetails t
          JOIN (SELECT @rownum := NULL, @category := '') r     
      ORDER BY t.contentType,t.contentid) X
      WHERE x.rank<=10;
```

Comment: Tank you Its working fine . But i do not  understand above query. Could you explain this query.

Comment: If it helps..you may choose this as accepted answer by green stick.   :)